# Flexslider in Bootstrap Grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, flexslider

I use FlexSlider in Bootstrap grid - 4 columns.
When I use `animation: 'fade'` grid its OK, but when I use `animation: 'slide'` grid its broken.

Animation fade - https://jsfiddle.net/s8etezf5/

Animation slide - https://jsfiddle.net/s8etezf5/1/

How to use "slide" animation in grid ?

Please help.

Have a Nice Weekend
Michael